# Is there a faster way to lowercase a string in C?

Tags: c, string

The most intuitive way to lowercase a string is to loop through it and lower each character:

```
do {
    *Str = tolower(*Str);
} while (*++Str);
```

However, like `memcpy()` being faster than copying each byte in a for loop, is there a faster way to lowercase a string in C? Like can I lower multiple chars at a time using bitwise magic or something?

Comment: You could try to vectorize or parallelize it but it's a good idea to give more information about why looping is too slow for your use case. How big is your input, for example?

Comment: Are you having a performance problem? I'd stick with this unless it's a confirmed hotspot in your program.

Comment: There's no standard C way that's better. There might be implementation-specific extensions.

Comment: @Barmar I am making the assumption that the character encoding is ASCII

Comment: You know that won't lowercase the first character? And it only works with single-byte character-sets?

Comment: @user13783520 Some of the answers at the linked question work with that assumption. They still all loop, but use different methods to lowercase each character.

Comment: @Barmar This is not a duplicate. I am asking for a _faster_ way, not _a_ way.

Comment: There's no faster way than looping with standard C.

Comment: If you have a perf problem with lower-casing a string, it's not from the lowercase loop itself. It's from the design that requires you to call to invoke that routine so much.

Comment: The ASCII assumption has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Barmar There's nothing faster? That's a strong claim. You may think optimization is unnecessary, but saying it's impossible is a whole nother matter.

Comment: @Barmar Maybe bitwise magic?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I said "with standard C". There may be implementation-specific optimizations.

Comment: @user13783520 There's bitwise magic in one of the answers at the linked question.

Comment: Standard C doesn't disallow loop unrolling, table lookups, and other generic optimizations. (Those may or may not be helpful but that's a matter for answers to address.) Also, the OP didn't say "standard C answers only". An answerer could very well write non-standard C with appropriate disclaimers.

Comment: the only thing I can think of is checking the assembly code to make sure tolower is being inlined because a function call is unnecessary here

Comment: @M47 `tolower()` is unlikely to be inlined, as the compiler probably cannot prove the locale is ASCII-only. Nor is it likely to try all that hard.

Comment: @Barmar: A program with `#if` statements that test prerequisites and implements a specialized fast solution if they are met and a general solution otherwise could be strictly conforming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Portable the lookup table will be probably the fastest. For a specific encoding (for example ASCII) some char arithmetic.

```
const char table[256] = {
                         ['a'] = 'a', ['A'] = 'a',
                         ['b'] = 'b', ['B'] = 'b',
                         ['c'] = 'c', ['C'] = 'c',
                         ['d'] = 'd', ['D'] = 'd',
                         ['e'] = 'e', ['E'] = 'e',
                         ['f'] = 'f', ['f'] = 'f',
                         ['g'] = 'g', ['g'] = 'g',
                         ['h'] = 'h', ['H'] = 'h',
                         ['i'] = 'i', ['I'] = 'i',
                         ['j'] = 'j', ['J'] = 'j',
                         /* etc etc */
};


char *strl_p(char *str)
{
    char c;
    char *saved = str;
    unsigned char *ustr = str;

    while(*ustr)
    {
        c = table[*ustr];
        if(c) *ustr = c;
        ustr++;
    }
    return saved;
}

char *strl_ascii(char *str)
{
    char c;
    char *saved = str;

    while(*str)
    {
        c = *str;
        if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') *str = c - ('A' - 'a');
        str++;
    }
    return saved;
}
```

Comment: Yes, such a small table is liable to be unbeatable. Unless one can just mindlessly or with 0x20 for any known stretch.